# Ios - Recongnise QRcode response Typee

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am using qr code in my app and it is giving me response also in the form of AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject. Here is my delegate which handles the response.

```
 func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {



    if strFound == ""
    {

    // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
    if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        qrCodeFrameVieww?.frame = CGRect.zero
        messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
        return
    }

    // Get the metadata object.
    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
        // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        //qrCodeFrameVieww?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

        if defaults.value(forKey: "beep") as! Bool != false
        {
            playSound()

        }
        if defaults.value(forKey: "vibrate") as! Bool != false
        {
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

            AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate), nil)

        }


        print("type is",metadataObj.type)

        print("metaDataObj",metadataObj)

         foundCode(code: metadataObj.stringValue as NSString)

        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {


            let stUrl = metadataObj.stringValue as String
            print("The Url Is \(stUrl)")

            if defaults.value(forKey: "copyToClipboard") as! Bool == true
            {
                UIPasteboard.general.string = stUrl



            }
```

}

My question is as qrcode code can scan vcards,phone numbers,emails,geo locations and Calendar Event etc.How would i get to know that what kind of data has i got in the response string like if it is a related to vcard or it is a url or a calender event??

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else {
  return
}
guard let codeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObject) else {
  return
}
switch codeObject.type {
  case .AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode:
    //...
  default:
    break
}
```